# Jetbrains Rider unable to run tests on .net core project

Tags: c#, .net-core, rider

When I first open my .net core project in Jetbrains Rider on Mac OSX and try to run unit tests they all say "Inconclusive" has anyone else experienced this issue before?

Comment: Looks like there could be a lot of different causes of this, and likewise a lot of different solutions: https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000057490-Unit-Test-Sessions-reports-Inconclusive-Test-not-run-?page=3#comments. One of the comments on that thread suggest enabling the "Verbose output in Options --> Unit Testing --> General (Show log entries with severity) in Resharper" and then seeing if there's any information/errors in the output after running the tests

Comment: Which test system are you using?

Comment: @ΩmegaMan I'm using NUnit

Comment: Create one using a different system. Also trying creating a different side test solution/project/test and see if the same happens.